# Probability of randomly generating a string

Tags: combinatorics

We are given the word: MISSISSIPPI

We break it into single characters like this:

```
M: 1x

I: 4x

S: 4x

P: 2x
```

Now we randomly construct a string of length 11 (same length as MISSISSIPPI) by using the characters in the list [M,I,I,I,I,S,S,S,S,P,P] (the characters we broke the string MISSISSIPPI into)

**What is the probability that the randomly generated string will be MISSISSIPPI again?**

My solution:

The probability will be ratio A/B, where A is the number of all variations that will spell MISSISSIPPI (counting character duplicates as different characters), and B is the number of all permutations of the string MISSISSIPPI (again, charcteer duplicated should be counted as different characters).

Applying this to calculations - it should be

```
(4!*4!*2!)/11!
```

I am not too sure about this, can anyone help?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: This is correct assuming all chars are different (i.e. of different colors)